# How can I focus attention on the intent of a question rather than details?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I asked what seemed a reasonable, understandable question [on an SE site](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/69163/should-a-programming-instructor-urge-students-to-use-more-efficient-practices) and got two good answers so far. *Commenters* focused on details that were not the point of the question. Please help me know how I can write Questions so as to avoid causing a debate about irrelevant details.

I am asking here because I have seen this on most other SE sites where I have posed questions so I think it applies generally.

Comment: This looks like something that belongs on Meta.Academics... you might want to not sound so much like a complaint and ask for actual help at how to prevent the situation.

Comment: Have a look at Yahoo Answers. That's your answer as to what happens if people aren't so nit-picky.

Comment: You jump to conclusions too quickly. It might just be academics that are nit-picky! Its our job.....

Comment: I cant downvote, but I agree its more a question for meta.academic, which there can lead to downvote.

Comment: @yagmoth555 Oh, shoot, you are being funny! You had me going there for a minute... Thought you were focusing on an irrelevant detail of this question... Cute!

Comment: Each community live on their own, like I participate on serverfault. I can you what to not forget in a question there, but I have no idea in academic.

Comment: cute, or a frenchy trying to read with is mobile! I prefer your term, hehe !

Comment: Sometimes those irrelevant details are more important than you think.  Consider them as you would any other contribution by those who are donating their time and expertise to help you.

Comment: You asked how to write better questions, the only answer is, respond positively to the feedback you recieve

Comment: @Ramhound Sounds a bit like Appreciative Inquiry. So I upvoted everything here. Story: I used to know someone who, when I said, "That won't work" would reply, "Be more positive!" So then I would say, "I am *positive* that it won't work." (That was not well-received.)

Answer (score 4):

The comments are your guide as to what details potential answerers are looking for in your question.

You can dismiss them as irrelevant, but it may be wiser to wonder why someone might want to spend their volunteered time asking them, before deciding whether to revise your question to cater for them, or to proceed with ignoring them.

Doing this should provide you with the experience to write your next question in a way that either pre-empts or precludes similar comments.

Comment: OK. My experience so far says that the fewer details I provide, the better. To get this question to go anywhere, I had to revise it several times to cut out information that provided context, but simply derailed people. I will have to learn how to ask questions that have no context whatsoever, like some kind of Platonic Form.

Comment: @nocomprende I'm not advocating no context but getting the amount of context right-sized is part of the art of focusing a question.